# FTP files in different folders using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp

I'm trying for an `ftp` script, that sends files in different folders within the same connection, but no luck with below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_NAME=host.server
username= user_name
passwd=   password
remote = /path_to_remote/folder
local =  /path_to_local/folder
folder=$1
pwd
ftp -in <<EOF
open $HOST_NAME
user $username $passwd
cd local/ 
lcd remote/ 
put a_filename_<timestamp>.txt 
mkdir $remote/$folder
cd $remote/$folder
lcd $local/$folder 
put b_filename.txt 
close 
bye
```

Adding to this, at run-time, is it possible to send only the latest files created in the last 10 minutes?

Comment: Re "*10 minutes before this script triggers*":  by "*this script*" does that mean the `bash` part, (i.e. the whole script), or the `ftp` portion?

Comment: Whenever above shell script triggers, it need to FTP file generated before 10mins.
For example: If the script scheduled to trigger @6AM, this script have to ftp the files generated after 5:50AM.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: By using shellcheck I haven't found any issues in commented code.

Comment: I modified the code, no issues reported in shellcheck. Is this a valid code??   
#!/bin/bash HOST_NAME=host.server
username=user_name
passwd=password
remote=/path_to_remote/folder local=/path_to_local/folder folder="$1" pwd ftp -in <<EOF open "$HOST_NAME" user "$username" "$passwd" cd local/ lcd remote/ put ls -t1 | head n 1 a_filename_*txt mkdir "$remote/$folder" cd "$remote/$folder" lcd "$local/$folder" put b_filename.txt close bye EOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_NAME=host.server
username=user_name
passwd=password
remote=/path_to_remote/folder
local=/path_to_local/folder
folder="$1"
pwd
ftp -in <<EOF
open "$HOST_NAME"
user "$username" "$passwd"
cd local/ 
lcd remote/ 
put a_filename_<timestamp>.txt 
mkdir "$remote/$folder"
cd "$remote/$folder"
lcd "$local/$folder" 
put b_filename.txt 
close 
bye
EOF
```

Notes:

1. The shell doesn't allow spaces next to `=`.
2. Quote variables.
3. OP code lacked closing `EOF`.

I've left the `<timestamp>` alone, that'd be a different Q.

Comment: Host server is offline. I'll test n update..
Is any possible condition to send latest files generated 10 minutes before this script triggers??